# Searching through text for a pattern and replacing the entire pattern in VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net, zpl-ii

I've been gathering information from all over the internet on how to look through a string of text for a pattern and replace it with something else.

I'm just starting to learn about RegEx and how to utilize them, as I think it bests fits my needs for the application. Basically what I need to do is look at a string that is read from a text file, which may contain up to 3 ZPL II label definitions, and replace some commands/parameters, before passing all the data to a wireless label printer.

For example, I need to find the media darkness command, ^MDxx, where xx is an integer that will set the darkness for the printed label. xx can be negative, positive, and up to but not always 2 digits (range is from -30 to 30). So, a particular ^MD command can be from 4 to 7 characters, and could be different for each label definition I'm processing at once. I need to replace all three of these commands with ^MD-13.

This is the code I've come up with based on my research, and am curious to know if I am doing anything wrong or if any adjustments need to be made.

```
Public Function ProcessLabelString(strInput As String) As String
    Dim strZPL As String = strInput

    Try
        Dim lstPatterns As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        'media tracking ^MNa,b - look for ^MN followed by a single letter, and optionally a comma followed by another letter
        lstPatterns.Add("\^MN[A-Za-z](\,[A-Za-z])?", "")
        'media darkness ^MDa - look for ^MD followed by an optional dash (for negative value) and up to two digits (valid values are -30 to 30)
        lstPatterns.Add("\^MD\-?\d{1,2}", "^MD-13")
        'label home ^LHx,y - look for ^LH followed by up to a five digit number, a comma, and another number up to five digits (valid values are 0 to 32000)
        lstPatterns.Add("\^LH\d{1,5},\d{1,5}", "^LH5,0")
        'print rate ^PRa,b,c - look for ^PR followed by up to two letters/numbers, and two optional sets of a comma with up to two letters/numbers (valid values for all three parameters are A-E or 1-14)
        lstPatterns.Add("\^PR[A-Ea-e0-9]{1,2}(\,[A-Ea-e0-9]{1,2})?(\,[A-Ea-e0-9]{1,2})?", "^PR2")
        Dim regExp As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex

        For Each pattern In lstPatterns
            regExp = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern.Key)
            strZPL = regExp.Replace(strZPL, pattern.Value)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    Return strZPL
End Function
```

where the strInput parameter is a string containing the contents of the ZPL II file (so it can contain anywhere from 1 to 3 labels). I do know that the commands will always be there, just not with the correct setting for the wireless printers I am working with.

EDIT: the following is a sample ZPL file that might be processed with this logic. There are normally a lot more ^FO commands, but as it contains sensitive information I copied and replaced some of the commands (they are all similar commands, just with different text values).

```
~JO
^XA^EG^XZ
^XA
^PMN
^MNY                             'need to find this
^MMT
^MTD
^MD20                            'need to find this
^LH10,10                         'need to find this
^LL1119
^PR6                             'need to find this
^JMA
^FO2,492^FR^GB785,2,2^FS
^FO8,725^FR^GB785,12,12^FS
^FO8,864^FR^GB785,2,2^FS
^FO8,1091^FR^GB785,12,12^FS
^FO275,492^FR^GB2,232,2^FS
^FO51,51^CI0^A0N,26,22^FR^FDCustomerName^FS
^FO51,81^CI0^A0N,26,26^FR^FDCompanyName^FS
^FO51,111^^CI0^A0N,26,26^FR^FDPhoneNumber^FS
^FO51,142^CI0^A0N,26,26^FR^FDAddress^FS
^FO51,173^CI0^A0N,26,26^FR^FDCityStateZip^FS
^PQ1
^XZ
~JO
^XA^EG^XZ
^XA
^PMN
^MNY                             'need to find this
^MMT
^MTD
^MD30                            'need to find this
^LH0,0                           'need to find this
^LL1219 
^PR6                             'need to find this
^JMA
^FO341,51^FR^GB2,195,2^FS
^FO51,248^FR^GB709,2,2^FS
^FO61,1172^FR^GB709,2,2^FS
^FO467,250^FR^GB2,171,2^FS
^FO61,538^FR^GB709,2,2^FS
^FO508,538^FR^GB2,293,2^FS
^FO61,417^FR^GB709,2,2^FS
^FO61,831^FR^GB709,2,2^FS
^FO51,51^CI0^A0N,26,22^FR^FDCustomerName^FS
^FO51,81^CI0^A0N,26,26^FR^FDCompanyName^FS
^FO51,111^^CI0^A0N,26,26^FR^FDPhoneNumber^FS
^FO51,142^CI0^A0N,26,26^FR^FDAddress^FS
^FO51,173^CI0^A0N,26,26^FR^FDCityStateZip^FS
^PQ1
^XZ
```

Comment: Can you post example(s) of the text you're searching through? I believe it would be helpful if we could see it..

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't even cross my mind! Edit made to include some sample file content that would be processed.